# File transfer between local folder and remote URL using WebDAV

Tags: webdav, winscp

I want to move files from local folder to remote URL in a scheduled way using WebDAV.

I found this URL useful but this shows the script to  transfer only single file, instead I want to transfer all files from a local folder to remote URL through winscp using WebDAV protocol:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

Any pointers for this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting):

```
open http://user:password@example.com/ 
put d:\path\* /home/user/
close
```

Read about [file masks](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

---

If you really need to move files (as opposite to copy), add the `-delete` switch to the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put):

```
put -delete d:\path\* /home/user/
```

---

For scheduling, see the WinSCP guide to [scheduling file transfers](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

Comment: @Martin..thanks for the reply....but here I am facing one issue .....when I open the session it shows me that I am connected to remote URL folder but I am not able to see files inside that folder...if I create any sub-folder inside that then it opens a path to that URL but actually it is not created when checked using Windows Explorer

Comment: @androidDev That looks like a separate issue, please start a new question for that and make sure you include logs.

Comment: @Martin...how to get the logs from WinSCP? when I run the script it shows that files are being transferred...Please check this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189223/files-are-not-showing-winscp